# Enable Google assistant ("Okay Google") on oneplus 3t

Tags: settings, oneplus-3, google-assistant

I have just bought a new Oneplus 3T device, and immediately upgraded to the newest Nougat 7.1.1

I do have the Google search bar on the main screen as a widget, and if I click the mic icon I can voice-search without any problems. However, just saying `Okay Google` near the device does not activate the search.

**How can I activate the `Okay Google` voice recognition on my Oneplus 3T device, please?**

Settings screenshot attached.

[image][image][image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to resolve "OK Google" detection problems:

Possible fixes

1. Language Pack settings

   - Make sure you are using the latest supported language pack. Check your Language settings

> In previous iterations of the Google voice search feature, it was only
>   able to respond to US English. ( More languages have been added since
>   then although many languages are still not supported). However, this
>   feature needs to be enabled, so if you don’t speak English as a first
>   language, this may be the issue. In order to enable other languages,
>   you should first ensure you have the latest feature of the Google
>   Search App. Then go to:
>
> 1. Settings
> 2. Voice
> 3. Languages
> 4. This will open a list of languages. Check the boxes next to the languages you want OK Google to recognize.
> 5. You can select up to five languages that OK Google will recognize a search request in.

*Updating your language pack may also solve your problem. Go to Voice > Search Language Settings > Offline Speech Recognition > English (US) > Update Available*

---

2. Whitelist from Battery optimisation

   - Make sure that "OK Google enrollment" is disabled in battery optimisation

---

3. Retrain OK Google voice model

Sometimes, for reasons unknown, Google Now doesn't retain the commands you have given it. In order to do this, you'll need to go to the Google Settings App,

> locate the Search & Now option, followed by Voice then OK Google
>   detection. Select Retrain Voice Model and say "OK Google" three times,
>   as you did when you initially set it up.

---

4. Check the hardware

   Few a times small bits of dust and debris can clog up the tiny hole that leads to your microphones. Use a safety pin or needle to investigate and dislodge anything that may be preventing good auditory reception.

---

5. Disabling and renabling OK Google

   - Go into Assistant settings, turn Ok Google detection off and then on, and check if  it starts working again.

---

6. Rebooting device

   - Try clearing cache of Google apps and reboot.

---

7. Update Google play services and Google App

   - Make sure your Google App is updated to the latest version . If not, just go to Google Play Store and update the Google App an Google play services

Acknowledgements

1. [Okay Google not working](http://trendblog.net/okay-google-not-working-fix/)
2. [Okay Google isn't working](https://www.androidpit.com/ok-google-is-not-working-here-s-how-to-fix-it)
3. [Okay Google not working](https://www.reddit.com/r/GooglePixel/comments/5ekwyx/ok_google_not_working/)
4. [How To Fix Android “Ok Google” Not Working Problem](https://www.technobezz.com/how-to-fix-android-ok-google-not-working-problem/)